# How to identify the status (checked Value) of the checkbox in hta using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, hta

Here is the code to read the `excel` data and result that data into `hta` table ,
and to write that edited data from `hta` to `excel`,
In my `hta` page [image: Excel Sample Data] that looks like this,if i select the required check boxes and click the `Click To Write` button the data are stored in the excelsheet by 'yes' or 'no' .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<HTA:application
Applicationname="MyApp"
BORDER="thin"
BORDERSTYLE="Normal"
Caption="yes"
ICON="D:\VBScriptTrainee\Ampeross-Qetto-Icon-developer.ico"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
NAVIGABLE="yes"
SYSMENU="yes"
VERSION="2.0"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"/>

<title>Read Excel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\VBScriptTrainee\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">

<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-color:#1abc9c;
}
P
{
font:bold 18px arial;
}
</style>
<script language="vbscript">

Public mySpan,selectexcel,objExcel,objWorkbook,rowCount,colCount,rowData,textData,sp,b,tempcol,checkData,i,j

On error resume next

Sub ReadExcelData()

  Set fileexcel =document.getelementbyid("file_id")
  file2=fileexcel.value
  'selectexcel      = inputbox("Enter the path","path here","D:\VBScriptTrainee\Sample.xlsx")
  Set objExcel      = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set objWorkbook   = objExcel.Workbooks.open(file2)
  objExcel.visible  = True

  rowCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
  colCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

  Dim mySpan

  'colCount=colCount+1  
  tempcol=colCount
  'MsgBox(tempcol)
  'MsgBox(colCount)
  rowData="<table border=2>"  

  For intRow=1 to rowCount step 1

   'rowData=null
    rowData = rowData & "<tr>"
    For intCol=1 to colCount step 1


        'if ((intRow =1) and (intCol=tempcol)) then
             'objExcel.Cells(intRow,tempcol).Value = "Flag"
             'intRow =IntRow + 1 
        'End if
         If ((intRow <> 1) and (intCol = tempcol)) then
             'objExcel.Cells(1,tempcol).Value = "Flag"

                     rowData = rowData & "<td>" & "<input type='checkbox' id='flag_id' name='flag' />" & "</td>"
                     'checkData = cStr(rowData)


         End If





            If (intRow=1) Then

                rowData= rowData & "<td>" & "<b><font color=red>" & objExcel.Cells(intRow,intCol).Value & "</font></b>"  & "</td>"          
            Else    

                    rowData = rowData & "<td><div contentEditable='True'>"  & objExcel.Cells(intRow,intCol).Value  & "</div></td>"

            End If        
    Next
                    rowData = rowData & "</tr>"

  Next
                    rowData =rowData & "</table>"

             Set mySpan=document.getelementbyid("Span_id_two")
             mySpan.innerHTML = rowData & "<br>"

             'Set myExcel=document.getelementbyid("selectfile")
             'myExcel.innerHTML = selectexcel




             MsgBox "Data readed successfully",vbInformation


              document.getElementById("file_id").accept = ".xlsx"
End sub

Sub WriteExcelData()  

       mwresult = Msgbox ("Are you Sure to Write ?",vbOKCancel)

        If (mwresult=1) then

           Set mySpan=document.getelementbyid("Span_id_two")
           textData=mySpan.innerHTML

           Set tab=document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)  

           mytable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).rows.length      
Msgbox("myTable (rows Length) " & mytable)         
           mytable1= document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).rows(0).cells.length  
Msgbox("myTable1 (rows Cells Length) " & mytable1)         

                For n = 0 to (mytable-1)  

                    For j = 0 To (mytable1-1)  

                        objExcel.Cells (n + 1, j + 1).Value = tab.Rows(n).Cells(j).innerHTML   
                        tableValue = tab.Rows(n).Cells(j).innerHTML 

                          If(tableValue="<INPUT id=flag_id type=checkbox CHECKED name=flag>") then

                                objExcel.Cells (n+1,mytable1).Value="Yes"

                          End If

                          If(tableValue="<INPUT id=flag_id type=checkbox name=flag>") then

                                objExcel.Cells (n+1,mytable1).Value="No"

                          End If                          

                    Next  

                Next   

                find ="<*>"
                rplace =" "

                objExcel.Cells.Replace find,rplace

                MsgBox "Data Exported Successfully",vbInformation                            

                objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
                Set objExcel=nothing

        End If

                If(mwresult=2) then
                     MsgBox "You Selected Cancel",vbInformation
                End If

End sub

</script>

</head>

<body>


<center>

   <img src="D:\VBScriptTrainee\Excel.png" height=200 width=300/>

</center>


<center>
<h1 align="center" style="color:blue"><img src="D:\VBScriptTrainee\icon-developer-icon.png" height=100px width=100px/>
Read Excel**</h1><br>
<a style="a.link:red;a.hover:green;a.visited:blue;" href="D:\VBScriptTrainee\Hta_Rules.hta">Rules*</a><br><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary text-primary" type="file" id="file_id" name="file_id" accept=".xlsx">
<br>

<button class="btn btn-success" name="Read" value="Click To Read" onclick="ReadExcelData()">Click To Read</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" name="Write" value="Click To Write" onclick="WriteExcelData()">Click To Write</button>



<br>
<br>
<p id="selectfile"></p>
<span ID="Span_id_two" Style="Color:blue;" name="text_name">
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</center>
<marquee direction="Right" style="color:red;">***Note : Select only excel files***</marquee>

</body>
</html>
```

But,I have identified that selected check value data by giving the `html` format,like this

from the above coding

```
If(tableValue="<INPUT id=flag_id type=checkbox CHECKED name=flag>") then

    objExcel.Cells (n+1,mytable1).Value="Yes"

End If

If(tableValue="<INPUT id=flag_id type=checkbox name=flag>") then

    objExcel.Cells (n+1,mytable1).Value="No"

End If
```

Is there any **alternative** way to identify the status (whether the checkbox is seleted or not) of the check box.

Here is my excel sheet..

[image: ExcelSheet]

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi,@Liam,@The_Black_Smurf,@ketan,@Rick Smith         I have posted a question what i have got an error,this is not a duplicate, but this question also received some answers ,i am new to javascript,thats why i am confusing.so, how can i delete this question,i dont have a permission to post a question for 6 months,what can i do for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your function definition of `toCelcius` has wrong syntax

```
 function toCelsius(f) { //removed var
   return (5/9) * (f-32);
 }
```

Your debugger tools (like console) available with your browsers to find these issues easily.

Comment: Tip: Debug with Chrome you'll easily find it. :-)

Comment: @MartinZhai absolutely

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function in JavaScript you don't have to include some kind of "type" like you in strongly typed languages. So adding a `var` in `toCelsius` argument list results in an error. Change it to this:

`function toCelsius(f)`